# How to secure Magento 2.x guest API

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api, security

I realized that it is possible to register customers through API without authentication.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/anonymous-api-security.html

Just make a POST call to https://example.com/rest/V1/customers
with JSON content:

```
{
    "customer":{
        "email": "customer@email.com",
        "firstname": "Customer Name",
        "lastname": "Customer Lastname"
    },
    "password": "UserPassword"
}
```

What would happen if an attacker exploited this possibility to "dirty" my customer database?

How can we protect?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved editing /vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
    <resources>
        <!-- resource ref="anonymous"/ -->
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

I changed ref="anonymous" to ref="self".

Now isn't accessible without authentication.

Comment: How can I use admin authentication token requried for my custom API. @Francesco Mineo